# Send ajax request with multiple types of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a application where user can set values via an interface and send ajax request (similar to as rest api).

I would like to know how to send data belong to multiple types in a single request. Example is given below,

## Form Data

```
var data = {'key1':'Key1Value','key2':'Key2Value'};
//content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

## Raw Data

```
var data = 'This is plain text raw value';
//content-type : text/plain
```

How should I combine above values to send the ajax request below,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/activity.php",
    data: {combined data},
    timeout: 3000,
    async: true,
    success: APIClient.baseSuccess,
    error: APIClient.baseError
  });
```

Comment: What is the server expecting to receive?

Comment: Each HTTP request should include only one `ContentType` header, so you cannot send *two different types* at the same time. You can either perform 2 requests, or encapsulate the request date into some common object; something like `{ url-encoded: { ... }, plain: '...' }` and update your server to manage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe send json object with those two as parameters?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/activity.php",
        data: {
            first: data_object,
            second: data_string
        },
        timeout: 3000,
        async: true,
        success: APIClient.baseSuccess,
        error: APIClient.baseError
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
var data = {'key1':'Key1Value','key2':'Key2Value'};
var text= 'This is plain text raw value';
data.text = text; //adds text to data object
```

Then

In `ajax`

```
data: data,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function.

```js
var dataText = 'This is plain text raw value';
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/activity.php",
  data: $.extend({
    key1:'Key1Value',key2:'Key2Value'
}, dataText),
  timeout: 3000,
  async: true,
  success: APIClient.baseSuccess,
  error: APIClient.baseError
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON to send all your various types of data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "arrayOfValues": {
            "key1": "Key1Value",
            "key2": "Key2Value"
        },
        "someString": "This is some tring value that I want to send"
    }
}
```

Assign this object to a variable and send it in your AJAX call. Of course you need to factor in what/how this data will be received server side.